# Shell scripting : want to login on some server, which are in same domain and execute command and exit

Tags: shell-script, command-line, python, perl

I have 10 unix servers, I want to log into them one by one, execute 4-5 lines of code, save the output and exit.

### For Example: 10 serves:

Intially at xyz server

Login in server 1 --> execute 4-5 lines --> send output to xyz server ---> exit

Login in server 2 --> execute 4-5 lines --> send output to xyz server ---> exit

....

Login in server 10 -->execute 4-5 lines --> send output to xyz server ---> exit

Finally on XYZ sever with output files.

---

Let's say, I want to execute some time commands,...
say backing time to one hour, taking new time as output, saving new time in some file on xyz server, with this format:

```
Server Name    New Time
===========    ========= 
Server1       Date and Time
Server2       Date and Time
```

Comment: ... and your question is ??? And what did you so far ? What kind of problems you are facing ?

Comment: You might be interested in [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible); your question title is exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of explanation in your initial question so i'm guessing it's something like this.

You can execute commands on remote servers with a remote call over SSH like so:

```
result=`ssh -t server1.mydomain.com "commands;separated;by;semicolons --with-args" > log-on-xyz.log 2>&1` echo "$result"
```

Do this for every server in your list by looping over them.
Finally you could echo the output of the log to the screen and remove it.

Commands can be "chained" by separating them with semicolons, arguments are allowed.
Also, you can use local variables as arguments in your remote call.

EDIT: Do note that this is BASH-script but should with a little modification also work with other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear as some information is missing.
Let's just try with what we have so far... Let's assume the 10 server ip address are 192.168.1.11..192.168.1.20:

```
#!/bin/bash

for host in 192.168.1.{11..20}
do
    echo "#############################################################################"
    echo "$host:"
    # check if host is alive, if positive, then execute command in remote server
    ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet user@$host exit
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];then 
        echo -e "\033[0;101m\033[1;37mOFFLINE\033[0m"
    else
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet user@$host "execute_command"
    fi
done
```

Now save the shell script and redirect stdout and stderr to log file.

```
./script.sh &> log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, so I am planning to change time on ~10 servers. but also want to make sure that time got changed, through some feedback.

Comment: For example (depending on distribution):
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet user@$host "date -s \"2016-03-12 12:48:00\""

Answer (score 0):

Install `pdsh`, then you can run commands like:

```
pdsh -w server[0-9],server10 'command1 ; command2 ;... ; command5' > logfile.txt
```

NOTE: if you don't want to enter passwords for each server, then you need to have an authorized_key installed on the remote servers.  If necessary, you can use the environment variable `PDSH_SSH_ARGS` to specify ssh options, including which identity file to use (`-i`).

The commands will be run **in parallel** on all servers, and output from them will be intermingled (with the hostname pre-pended to each output line).  You can view the output nicely formatted and separated by host using `pdsh`'s `dshbak` utility:

```
dshbak logfile.txt | less
```

Alternatively, you can pipe through dshbak before redirecting to a logfile:

```
pdsh -w server[0-9],server10 'command1 ; command2 ;... ; command5' | 
    dshbak > logfile.txt
```

IMO it's better to save the raw log file and use `dshbak` when required, but that's just my subjective preference.  For remote commands that produce only a single line of output (e.g. `uname` or `uptime`), `dshbak` is overly verbose as the output is nicely concise.  e.g. from my home network:

```
# pdsh -g all uptime
kali:  12:03:18 up 33 days, 23 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.21, 0.06, 0.06
hanuman:  12:03:37 up 10 days, 21:59,  2 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.05
indra:  12:02:57 up 13 days,  1:12,  3 users,  load average: 0.30, 0.26, 0.30
ganesh:  12:03:10 up 6 days, 10:11,  6 users,  load average: 1.18, 1.34, 1.35
```

You can define hosts and groups of hosts in a file called `/etc/genders` and then specify the host group with `pdsh -g` instead of `pdsh -w`.  e.g. with an `/etc/genders` file like this:

```
server1  all,web
server2  all,web
server3  all,mail
server4  all,mail
server5  all,mysql
server6  all,mysql
```

`pdsh -g all uname -a` will run `uname -a` on all servers.  `pdsh -g web uptime` will run `uptime` only on server1 and server 2.  `pdsh -g web,mysql df -h /` will run `df` on servers 1, 2, 5, and 6.  and so on.

BTW, one odd thing about `pdsh` is that it is configured to use `rsh` by default instead of `ssh`.  You need to either:

1. use `-R ssh` on the pdsh command line (e.g. `pdsh -R ssh -w server[0-9] ...`
2. `export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh` before running `pdsh`
3. run `echo ssh > /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default` to set `ssh` as the permanent default.

---

If `pdsh` is not packaged for your distro, you can find it at LLNL: https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html

---

There are several other tools that do the same basic job as `pdsh`.  I've tried several of them and found that they're generally more hassle to set up and use.  `pdsh` pretty much just works with zero or minimal configuration.